# populating and listing a one to many hash data structure

Tags: perl, hash

The script below lists all the jobs in parses a config file, and takes out just the
executable that runs the job - either a perl or shell script. Then it opens the
executable, and goes through it line by line and takes out the file paths that it reads
in and the paths that it outputs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fh_rmancfg, '<', "/data/autosys-us.cfg"
    or die "can't open file $!" ;
while ( my $cfg_line = <$fh_rmancfg>) {
    if ($cfg_line =~ /executable/) {
        my $cut_cfg_line = substr "$cfg_line", 13 ;
        if ($cut_cfg_line =~ /(\/\S*\.(sh|pl|ksh))/) {
            chomp($cut_cfg_line);
            open my $fh_cut_cfg, '<', $cut_cfg_line
                or warn qq{Can't open file "$cut_cfg_line" : $! } ;
            while (my $path = <$fh_cut_cfg>) {
                if ($path =~ /(\"\/\S*)\"/) {
                    print "$cut_cfg_line --->  $path";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works great, except when i pump these values into a hash the
keys get overwritten - Please note that sometimes one key has one value,
sometimes one key has zero or many values.

```
program_1  -->  filepath_one
program_1  -->  filepath_two
program_1  -->  filepath_three
program_2  -->  filepath_one
program_2  -->  filepath_two
program_2  -->  filepath_three
program_2  -->  filepath_four
program_3  -->  filepath_one
program_4  -->  filepath_one
program_4  -->  filepath_one
program_4  -->  filepath_two
program_5  -->  filepath_one
program_5  -->  filepath_two
program_5  -->  filepath_thee
program_5  -->  filepath_four
program_5  -->  filepath_five
program_5  -->  filepath_six
program_5  -->  filepath_seven
program_5  -->  filepath_eight
```

I need a data structure that will enter a unique key
but has many values.  I am trying to figure out what this
structure is and how to get the values in to the structure.

```
program_1  -->  filepath_one
           -->  filepath_two
           -->  filepath_three
program_2  -->  filepath_one
           -->  filepath_two
           -->  filepath_three
           -->  filepath_four
program_3  -->  filepath_one
program_4  -->  filepath_one
           -->  filepath_one
           -->  filepath_two
program_5  -->  filepath_one
           -->  filepath_two
           -->  filepath_thee
           -->  filepath_four
           -->  filepath_five
           -->  filepath_six
           -->  filepath_seven
           -->  filepath_eight
```

Comment: Use a hash of arrays where your keys are `program_x` and the arrays are the filepaths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, when you do something like this:

```
$hash{key} = "value";
$hash{key} = "new value";
```

The original value is gone. Fortunately, Perl 5 allows you to use [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). Perl References allow you to do things like have a hash key point to an array of values instead of a single value.

```
$hash{key} = [];   # The value is a reference to an array
$hash{key}->[0] = "value";
$hash{key}->[1] = "new value";
```

Now, `$hash{key}` contains two values! The array is called a *reference* and sometimes even *an anonymous array* because the array itself has no variable name associated with it.

You can create a *reference* by putting a backslash in front of the variable:

$array_reference = \@array;

To *dereference* (that is, turn the reference back into an array), you put the correct [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) in front of it:

my @new_array = @{ $array_reference };

Using references allows Perl to use much more complex data structures. Instead of simply assigning a value to a hash, you could use `push` to push the values into an *array reference* that the particular hash value points to:

```
my %hash;
$hash{key} = [];          # This key is an array reference
for each $value ( qw(value1 value2 value3 ) ) {
    push @{ $hash{key} }, $value;
}
```

Read the [Perl Tutorial on References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and it should give you an idea how you can use a *hash of arrays* to store all of your values.

Comment: And once you've become comfortable with the idea of references, you can drop the initial `$hash{key} = [];` and simply do `push @{ $hash{key} }, $value;` thanks to the magic of [autovivification](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#autovivification).

Comment: I like the `$hash{key} = [];` line because it documents that I an expecting an array reference. Most people don't put it though.

Answer (score 4):

Use need to use hash of arrays if you are going to have keys that repeat. You can read more about different data structures in [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Here is a quick example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hashofArrays;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $key, $value ) = split;
    push @{ $hashofArrays{ $key } }, $value;
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%hashofArrays;

__DATA__
program_1 filepath_one
program_1 filepath_two
program_1 filepath_three
program_2 filepath_one
program_2 filepath_two
program_2 filepath_three
program_2 filepath_four
program_3 filepath_one
program_4 filepath_one
program_4 filepath_one
program_4 filepath_two
program_5 filepath_one
program_5 filepath_two
program_5 filepath_thee
program_5 filepath_four
program_5 filepath_five
program_5 filepath_six
program_5 filepath_seven
program_5 filepath_eight
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'program_5' => [
                           'filepath_one',
                           'filepath_two',
                           'filepath_thee',
                           'filepath_four',
                           'filepath_five',
                           'filepath_six',
                           'filepath_seven',
                           'filepath_eight'
                         ],
          'program_3' => [
                           'filepath_one'
                         ],
          'program_2' => [
                           'filepath_one',
                           'filepath_two',
                           'filepath_three',
                           'filepath_four'
                         ],
          'program_1' => [
                           'filepath_one',
                           'filepath_two',
                           'filepath_three'
                         ],
          'program_4' => [
                           'filepath_one',
                           'filepath_one',
                           'filepath_two'
                         ]
        };
```